# Crontab won't execute vlc live stream

Tags: cron

Im trying to auto start and stop a rtps stream via vlc in the crontab:

```
sudo crontab -e
15 9 * * * vlc -vvv rtsp://user:pwd@xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/stream1
```

and

```
nano /etc/crontab
14 9 * * * camera vlc -vvv rtsp://admin:TmT01@80.112.134.3:554/stream1
```

If i paste the command in the terminal, the stream opens without a problem, but when I was testing it by making it a cronjob this way and scheduling it 2 minutes in the future to test it, nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong or can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5):

That is because a crontab job has no connection to your desktop. The purpose of the crontab is to run headless jobs -- without any interactive output or graphical display, and only with logging messages to a file. Crontab has no connection to your graphical display. However, you can try to give the information about your display by setting the `DISPLAY` environmental variable.

Something like this might work:

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 vlc -vvv rtsp://your.url 2>&1 > /tmp/vlc.log
```

Note that you will still not be able to see the vlc output in your current terminal -- crontab runs the schedule without having *any* idea what your current terminal or terminal emulator is. Therefore, if you want verbosity or logging, you should save the output to a file.

Post scriptum: Erik is right, you will also need to deal with XAUTHORITY if your command is started by root. You will not have to do that if you are starting vlc from your own crontab, though.

Comment: And maybe you also need to set the environment variable **XAUTHORITY**

Comment: Well, I'm not sure when XAUTHORITY is needed; I don't think it is needed if it is a personal crontab. It is then being run as the same user who runs X so it should not have a problem with that.

Comment: On my **Ubuntu 13.04** computer `/usr/bin/X` is run by root and I see that **XAUTHORITY** is set for my user to the value `/home/erik/.Xauthority`. But anyway I added a `maybe` in the previous comment to be safe ;-)

Comment: Well, I'm not arguing with you, +1. Yes, the X process itself runs with root privileges, but only you have the [X]authority to start GUI programs in it.